# R: reading multiple csv files from a folder

Tags: r, lapply

I have folder with 100 csv files that I want to read in R. The csv files are located in folder `C:/test/data/`. Here's what I am doing:

```
setwd("C:/test/")

temp <- list.files(path=paste0(getwd(),"/data/"), pattern="*.csv")
named.list <- lapply(tmin.temp, read.csv)
```

The issue is that I do not want to change my working directory (I want to keep the working directory `C:/test/`). So the second line of code throws up an error since `read.csv` cannot find my csv files in my working directory. I also tried doing this:

```
temp <- list.files(path=paste0(getwd(),"/data/"), pattern="*.csv")
named.list <- lapply(tmin.temp, read.csv(path=paste0(getwd(),"/data/"))
```

But this generates an error since the `read.csv` does not take this kind of argument. I can always write a `for` loop to read all files but I am looking for a solution that corrects the above approach.

Thank you.

Comment: You should use `list.files(path="data", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)`

Comment: Is there are a reason why you don't/can't want to use the full paths to the files?

Comment: `named.list <- lapply(temp, function(x) read.csv(path=paste0(getwd(),"/data/", x))`

Comment: docendro's solution is good. Didn't know about `full.names = TRUE`, awesome.

Comment: Docendo: that is really great. Happy to accept it as an asnwer if you post it as a solution.